# How to build char* from array of char*

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

Please have a look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
        const char * cmd;
        const char * help;
} CmdEnum;

static CmdEnum cmd_enum[] = {
        {"help", "This help..."},
        {"first", "The first command"},
        {"second", "The second command"},
};

void main()
{
    int i,n;
    char *out = "";

        n = sizeof(cmd_enum) / sizeof(CmdEnum);
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            char *oldOut = out;
            CmdEnum cmd = cmd_enum[i];
            asprintf(&out, "%s%s -> %s\n", oldOut, cmd.cmd, cmd.help);
            if(i>0) free(oldOut);
        }

    printf("%s", out);
    printf("Done.\n");
}
```

Is this a good way to build a text from the CmdEnum?
Is there a "nicer" way do define `cmd` in the first place as to avoid the `if(i>0) free...`?
Or am I doing something entirely wrong?

**EDIT:**
After reading larsmans' answer I modified `main` to:

```
int main()
{
    int i,n, copied, siz;
    char *out, *cursor;
    siz = 1;// 1 for NUL char
    n = sizeof(cmd_enum) / sizeof(CmdEnum);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        siz += strlen(cmd_enum[i].cmd) + strlen(cmd_enum[i].help) + strlen(":\n\t\n\n");
    }

    out = malloc(siz);
    if(!out)
    {
        printf("Could not alloc!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    cursor = out;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        copied = snprintf(cursor, siz, "%s:\n\t%s\n\n", cmd_enum[i].cmd, cmd_enum[i].help);
        if(copied < 0 || copied >= siz)
        {
            printf("snprintf failed: %i chars copied.\n", copied);
            return 1;
        }

        cursor += copied;
        siz -= copied;
    }

    printf("%s", out);
    printf("Done.\n");
    free(out);
    return 0;
}
```

(Note: I also changed the output format...)

Comment: First of all, this code doesn't compile.

Comment: @cnicutar, your answer was at least half-right...

Comment: `void main` is the issue here.

Comment: @sarnold What part of it was right? This code only frees what is allocated by asprintf.

Comment: @Jim, the bit that was right was pointing out that the `if (i > 0)` construction was necessary because the initial `""` wasn't allocated by `malloc(3)`. larsmans's answer is a significantly better approach to solving the underlying problem, but I thought he did a good job pointing at some awkward code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good way to build a text from the CmdEnum?

Yes, except that `asprintf` is not portable (although you can define it easily in terms of `snprintf` for platforms that don't have it) and you're not checking error returns. `void main` isn't valid C btw.

> Is there a "nicer" way do define cmd in the first place as to avoid the if(i>0) free...?

You could allocate the whole string beforehand.

```
size_t i, siz = 1;  // 1 for NUL char
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    siz += strlen(cmd_enum[i].cmd) + strlen(cmd_enum[i].help) + strlen(" -> \n");

char *out = malloc(siz);
// check for errors
```

then build the string with `snprintf`. This saves you some `malloc`'ing and error checking in the loop.

Comment: sizeof will return the space for trailing '\0', you'll need that only once for the entire string.

Comment: @yi_H: true, but such a little over-allocation won't hurt, will it?

Comment: "*I* don't know - Mr Wentworth just told me to come in here and say that there was trouble at the mill, that's all - I didn't expect a kind of Spanish Inquisition."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I googled a bit on ̀`void main(void)` and will avoid it in the future.

Comment: @Nils: I have no time to actually compile and run it, but it looks perfectly fine now.

Comment: @larsmans: Well, it compiles and it runs ;) So - "looks perfectly fine" is a perfectly good answer. Thanks.